# Slider plugin of HTML theme won't work when I install it on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've bought a HTML theme and I want to make Wordpress manage the content of it.

The problem is that when I put the code from index.html on index.php to make it a valid Wordpress theme, the Revolution Slider Plugin stops working. The images from the slider are displayed on top of each other like if no plugin were installed.

The Revolution Slider plugin files are inside the theme folder, in a folder called "rs-plugin".

This is the header of my header.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta name="keywords" content="pousada, flores do cerrado, pousada flores do cerrado, pousada pirenopolis, pousada pirenópolis, flores pousada, flores do cerrado pirenópolis, pousada flores pirenópolis, aconchego, pousada calma, pousada família, pousada casal, pousada aconchegante, fim de semana casal pirenopolis, fim de semana pirenopolis, pousada ferias pirenopolis, pousada barata pirenopolis" />
    <meta name="description" content="Pousada Flores do Cerrado - O bálsamo do conforto e aconchego em Pirenópolis. ">
    <meta name="author" content="Ansonika">
    <title>Country Holidays - Premium site template for a country accommodation.</title>

    <!-- Favicons-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" type="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/image/x-icon">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/apple-touch-icon-57x57-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="72x72" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="114x114" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/x-icon" sizes="144x144" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">

    <!-- Google web fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gochi+Hand' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- BASE CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/style.css" />
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- REVOLUTION SLIDER CSS -->
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/css/extralayers.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.enablelog.js"> </script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.js"> </script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"> </script>


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <?php wp_head();?>

</head>
```

This is the part of the code where the plugin comes and should be working:

```
<!-- Slider -->
    <div class="tp-banner-container">
        <div class="tp-banner">
            <ul>
                <!-- SLIDE  -->
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Intro Slide">
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/cafe-1-grande.jpg" alt="slidebg1" data-lazyload="img/slides_bg/slide_1.jpg" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption white_heavy_40 customin customout text-center text-uppercase" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="-20" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;" data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="1000" data-start="1700" data-easing="Back.easeInOut" data-endspeed="300" style="z-index: 5;max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">Country Holidays pleasure
                    </div>
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0 text-center" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="15" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2600" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.05" data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 9; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
                        <div style="color:#ffffff; font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
                            Rooms / Country activities / Pleasure</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="70" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2900" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-linktoslide="next" style="z-index: 12;"><a href='rooms_list.html' class="button_intro">View Rooms</a> <a href='all_activities.html' class=" button_intro outline">Activities</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <!-- SLIDE  -->
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Intro Slide">
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/redario-1.jpg" alt="slidebg1" data-lazyload="img/slides_bg/slide_6.jpg" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption white_heavy_40 customin customout text-center text-uppercase" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="-20" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;" data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="1000" data-start="1700" data-easing="Back.easeInOut" data-endspeed="300" style="z-index: 5; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">Discover fantastic places
                    </div>
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0 text-center" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="15" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2600" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.05" data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 9; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
                        <div style="color:#ffffff; font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
                            We offer a variety of services and options</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="70" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2900" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-linktoslide="next" style="z-index: 12;"><a href='rooms_list.html' class="button_intro">View Rooms</a> <a href='all_activities.html' class=" button_intro outline">Activities</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <!-- SLIDE  -->
                <li data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="500" data-saveperformance="on" data-title="Intro Slide">
                    <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/lazer-1.jpg" alt="slidebg1" data-lazyload="img/slides_bg/slide_4.jpg" data-bgposition="center top" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption white_heavy_40 customin customout text-center text-uppercase" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="-20" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:90;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:1;scaleY:1;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:200;transformOrigin:50% 0%;" data-customout="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0.75;scaleY:0.75;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="1000" data-start="1700" data-easing="Back.easeInOut" data-endspeed="300" style="z-index: 5; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">Enjoy Countryside  Activities
                    </div>
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0 text-center" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="15" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2600" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.05" data-endelementdelay="0.1" style="z-index: 9; max-width: auto; max-height: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
                        <div style="color:#ffffff; font-size:16px; text-transform:uppercase;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);">
                            Rooms / Country activities / Pleasure</div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
                    <div class="tp-caption customin tp-resizeme rs-parallaxlevel-0" data-x="center" data-y="center" data-hoffset="0" data-voffset="70" data-customin="x:0;y:0;z:0;rotationX:0;rotationY:0;rotationZ:0;scaleX:0;scaleY:0;skewX:0;skewY:0;opacity:0;transformPerspective:600;transformOrigin:50% 50%;" data-speed="500" data-start="2900" data-easing="Power3.easeInOut" data-splitin="none" data-splitout="none" data-elementdelay="0.1" data-endelementdelay="0.1" data-linktoslide="next" style="z-index: 12;"><a href='rooms_list.html' class="button_intro">View Rooms</a> <a href='all_activities.html' class=" button_intro outline">Activities</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div id="general_decor"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Slider -->
```

I've been stuck on this for a while. Where am I missing?

Comment: Any javascript error, or something we can start ?

Comment: No javascript error. It seems like it doesn't even come to execute the plugin.

Comment: Ok, where is your "calling revolution function" code.

Comment: Maybe it might be missing some reference to the plugin so the code can locate its files and execute them. But where? And is it right to put the plugin on the theme folder? Ps.: It's a HTML plugin and not a Wordpress plugin.

Comment: ebilgin, I don't know. I've just copied the content from the original HTML theme in index.html and pasted it on index.php form Wordpress, adjusting just the path of the files. I supposed there was no need to make such function since on the original theme it works perfectly with that code.

Comment: Your money would have been better spent buying a wordpress theme maybe, just saying.

Comment: ArtisiticPhoenix, I thought the website I bought it only sold Wordpress themes, but apparently they sell HTML also

Comment: Make sure copied everything correctly. There must be a execution code in somewhere.

Comment: Can you provide html theme's code ? Maybe i can found your execution code.

Comment: Sounds like you are missing your css, can you open the css files by pasting the links for them in the url?

Comment: ebilgin, there it is: http://pastebin.com/qdwt3puH

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix, they all open correctly when I paste their link on the browser. So I don't think it's the CSS

Comment: <script src="js/revolution_func.js"></script> I think there it is.. You'll find your execution code in this script. Just copy it too..

Comment: ebilgin, tried it and it didnt work still. :(